# Where To Put JAR Files To Avoid Conflicts?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, weblogic

Windows XP Pro
WebLogic 11g
Tomcat 7
JDK 1.6

I've been putting supplemental JAR files in

```
JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext ( a JDK installation )
```

for years.  It is much more convenient than altering my CLASSPATH and everything I develop has access to one set of stuff in one place.

I need a different or better approach though.

I recently installed WebLogic 11g on on my computer.   Since I do not like having multiple JDKs or JVMs on my machine I set my JAVA_HOME variable to point to there.

I then put a servlet-api.jar there to compile my webapps.   All was well.

Then I installed Tomcat 7.   Tomcat 7 has its own servlet-api.jar in CATALINA_HOME/lib.   Having a servlet-api.jar in CATALINA_HOME/lib and one in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext causes Tomcat 7 to throw errors.  However, I need one in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext to compile my webapps.

Is there a more graceful solution than deleting servelt-api.jar from CATALINA_HOME/lib ?

Thanks

Comment: yes, dont put things in the jdk, put them on the classpath of the project

Comment: My problem with that approach is that is what the jdk/jre/lib/ext directory is for...have one place, always on the classpath, to put things.

Comment: of course that won't work at all if you want to use the same JDK to run different versions of the given product. you can also run into classloader problems that way. (EE servers may load their own, different, servlet classes, then you'll start to get weird errors..) I use maven to manage my dependencies for me, without the pitfalls of putting things in lib/ext

Comment: @Steve no, not really, you should only use .ext if you are in need of an altered JRE to be distributed among several machines. Even then you should be very careful what you do. Any update of the JRE will mess up your classpath. `/ext` is *not* for applications.

Comment: If you are running your app from tomcat you should put your jar files inside a lib folder within your webapplication (war)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the Jar in `/ext`, but compile against your actual EE framework. In that way you won't run into problems when the version of the `.jar`s delivered with your Tomcat (or other EE installation) changes. So don't put the `.jar` in ext anymore and change the build path to your *actual* EE environment.

Comment: It is easy enough to use your answer with Tomcat.  I just point to the Tomcat/lib directory.  I really couldn't tell if there was a central lib in WebLogic 11g.

Comment: You will have to decide what your target runtime is. If there are more, you should configure them separately - and you would be quickly in need of an automated build environment if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java Tutorial: The Extension Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/index.html):

> The extension mechanism provides a standard, scalable way to make
>   custom APIs available to all applications running on the Java
>   platform. Java extensions are also referred to as optional packages.
>   This trail may use both terms interchangeably.
>
> Extensions are groups of packages and classes that augment the Java
>   platform through the extension mechanism. The extension mechanism
>   enables the runtime environment to find and load extension classes
>   without the extension classes having to be named on the class path. In
>   that respect, extension classes are similar to the Java platform's
>   core classes. That's also where extensions get their name -- they, in
>   effect, extend the platform's core API.
>
> Since this mechanism extends the platform's core API, **its use should
>   be judiciously applied**. Most commonly **it is used for well
>   standarized interfaces such as those defined by the Java Community
>   Process**, although it may also be appropriate for site wide
>   interfaces.